# Cómo evitar valores repetidos en barchart de reporte jaspersoft

Tags: java, jasper-reports

tengo un problema al generar un reporte con varios registros de personas, en el cual pinto una grafica de scores tipo BarChart como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La gráfica esta en un detail band, ya que se debe pintar por cada persona que venga en los registros.

El problema está en que cuando son varios registros, las gráficas pintan el mismo valor para todas las personas, lo cual esta mal. Estoy usando jaspersoft studio 6.6 y spring boot.

```
<barChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="false" evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="191" y="194" width="170" height="110" uuid="65065fea-fdcc-447d-8f6a-84f741e1a563"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="dataSetScore" uuid="d1192fc3-de24-49be-baf6-c028bc66146b">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listaScore})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["SERIES 1"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{anio}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{score}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot isShowLabels="true" isShowTickLabels="true" isShowTickMarks="true">
                    <plot>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#5670DB"/>
                    </plot>
                    <itemLabel color="#000000">
                        <font size="6"/>
                    </itemLabel>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" verticalTickLabels="true" axisLineColor="#000000">
                            <labelFont>
                                <font size="7"/>
                            </labelFont>
                            <tickLabelFont>
                                <font size="6"/>
                            </tickLabelFont>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000">
                            <labelFont>
                                <font size="6"/>
                            </labelFont>
                            <tickLabelFont>
                                <font size="6"/>
                            </tickLabelFont>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                    <rangeAxisMinValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></rangeAxisMinValueExpression>
                    <rangeAxisMaxValueExpression><![CDATA[1000]]></rangeAxisMaxValueExpression>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
```

Comment: Y cómo estás generando el reporte? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade todo el código relevante.

Comment: Gracias por añadir el jrxml correspondiente. Nos falta ver cómo le entregas los datos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, el problema estaba en la propiedad llamada Evaluation Time del chart. El valor por defecto es Evaluation Time = Report y lo cambié a Evaluation Time = Band.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos los paso con un field de tipo lista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]